# Хочу сделать RESTFull API на Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, rest, crud

Пробую сделать RESTFull API на Yii2. До этого делал RESTFull только на ларавеле.
Сначала решил попробовать по инструкции https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/rest-quick-start.
Делаю в опенсервере. Установил версию basic. Страница index открылась, Gii тоже открылся. Подключил базу данных в конфиге. Далее по инструкции создал контроллер User в папке C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\controllers:

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

    class UserController extends ActiveController
    {
        public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
    }
```

Вставил

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'],
    ],
]
```

и

```
'request' => [
    'parsers' => [
        'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
    ]
]
```

в файл C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\config\web.php

При попытке сделать по инструкции

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" "http://testyii2/users"
```

Получаю

```
$ curl -i "http://testyii2/users"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 19 Dec 2020 14:56:56 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 2104
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController

        public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
}<pre>An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\controllers\UserController.php on line 1. in C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Response.php:370
Stack trace:
#0 C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Response.php(343): yii\web\Response-&gt;sendHeaders()
#1 C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(136): yii\web\Response-&gt;send()
#2 C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php(135): yii\web\ErrorHandler-&gt;renderException(Object(yii\base\UnknownClassException))
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler-&gt;handleException(Object(yii\base\UnknownClassException))
#4 {main}
Previous exception:
yii\base\UnknownClassException: Unable to find &#039;app\controllers\UserController&#039; in file: C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2/controllers/UserController.php. Namespace missing? in C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php:296
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\BaseYii::autoload(&#039;app\\controllers...&#039;)
#1 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call(&#039;app\\controllers...&#039;)
#2 C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(637): class_exists(&#039;app\\controllers...&#039;)
#3 C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(596): yii\base\Module-&gt;createControllerByID(&#039;user&#039;)
#4 C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(522): yii\base\Module-&gt;createController(&#039;index&#039;)
#5 C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(104): yii\base\Module-&gt;runAction(&#039;user/index&#039;, Array)
#6 C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(392): yii\web\Application-&gt;handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#7 C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\web\index.php(12): yii\base\Application-&gt;run()
#8 {main}</pre>
```

То есть не находит контроллер UserController?

```
Previous exception:
yii\base\UnknownClassException: Unable to find &#039;app\controllers\UserController&#039; in file: C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2/controllers/UserController.php. Namespace missing? in C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php:296
```

Не может ли это быть из за разных слешей:

```
C:\OSPanel\domains\testYii2/controllers/UserController.php
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Решено: была проблема с опенсервером